# Nested if else statement not executing in Python

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, nested, sleep

I am trying to write a program in Python 3 that will average the user's input for hours of sleep and then return a message based on the average. The program will not print anything. There is not an error that shows.

This is the first  if block I wrote. I meant for the program to average the hours, then print a statement based on the age and the average of the hours. For example, if the user is 18 and sleeps an average of 8 hours, then it would print |"sleeps too little".

```
  import sys

  h1 = float(sys.argv[1]) 
  h2 = float(sys.argv[2])
  h3 = float(sys.argv[3])
  h4 = float(sys.argv[4])
  h5 = float(sys.argv[5])
  age = float(sys.argv[6])

  sleeph =(h1+h2+h3+h4+h5)/5

 if (age >18 and age < 25):
    if(sleeph>7 and sleeph<9):
        print(name,"  sleeps too little")
elif(sleeph>= 10 and sleeph<= 11):
    print(name,"sleeps enough")
else:
    print(name, " sleeps too much") `
```

I can't tell what I am missing. I think it is executing after the first if statement and then exiting the program. Any ideas?

Comment: Your indentation is wrong; that could be part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your second 'if' statement checks for less than 9 and the 'elif' checks for greater than or equal to 10, which leaves nine out completely. Also you are ignoring any sleep hours less than 7 which would be most of the people between 18 and 25 ;)

```
name = 'Ranger Rick'
    sleeph = 9 
    age = 19
    if (age >18 and age < 25):
        if(sleeph<9):
            print(name,"  sleeps too little")
        elif(sleeph>= 9 and sleeph<= 11):
            print(name,"sleeps enough")
        else:
            print(name, " sleeps too much")
```

Comment: I modeled the rest of my program to this and it worked after that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation seems to be wrong. You should correct it first.

```
h = [7.8, 4.5, 6.7, 10, 9]
age = int(input('Enter your age'))
sleeph = (h[0] + h[1] + h[2] + h[3] + h[4]) / 5
if age > 18 and age < 25:
    if sleeph > 7 and sleeph < 9:
        print('Sleeping too little')
    elif sleeph >= 10 and sleeph <= 11:
        print('Sleeping enough')
    else:
        print('Sleeping too much')
```

**Output**

```
Enter your age23
Sleeping too little
```

The `if-else`ladder should be indented inside the main if block as all the `sleeph` conditions are to be checked for the age range 18 to 25. Further, if age conditions also have to be checked, the indentation will be like

```
h = [7.8, 4.5, 6.7, 10, 9]
age = int(input('Enter your age'))
sleeph = (h[0] + h[1] + h[2] + h[3] + h[4]) / 5
if age > 18 and age < 25:
    if sleeph > 7 and sleeph < 9:
        print('Sleeping too little')
    elif sleeph >= 10 and sleeph <= 11:
        print('Sleeping enough')
    else:
        print('Sleeping too much')
elif age >= 25 and age <= 40:
    # if - else ladder for sleeph repeated
else:
    # Repeat the if - else ladder of sleeph for age > 40
```

Hope this resolves your issue.